# Encrypt the password column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm wondering how to encrypt my password column in SQL Server 2008. I've read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx) article, but I still have no idea how... is there an easier to understand tutorial? Thanks!

Comment: Your link to "this article" appears to have gone AWOL.

Comment: oops, here goes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx

Comment: @user133466 - Why are you not storing hashes of the passwords from the source application?

Comment: can you show me an article on that? I'm using ASP.net (VB.net)

Comment: @user133466 - If you use Forms Authentication with the SqlMembershipProvider, it will handle all the hashing for you.

Comment: I would agree with Thomas. Handle the encryption in the business logic and store the result in the table. You don't need to know the actual passwords then, just compare the hashes. Might be an idea to add some more tags indicating your stack - C#, VB, Java, ASP, Java? Super easy in ASP.Net for example: http://www.adventuresindevelopment.com/2009/05/23/a-simple-way-to-hash-passwords-in-aspnet/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual practice is to store a hash of the password.  Like:

```
HASHBYTES('SHA1', convert(varbinary(32), @password))
```

With a hash, you can verify if the password matches, but you don't know the password itself.  So even if a hacker gains complete access to your database, he still does not know the passwords.

There are many tutorials [on the web](http://www.google.com/search?q=sqlserver%20store%20password%20hash).

Comment: It's also not a bad idea to use a salt value. A random (crytographically strong) int or bigint can work nicely.

Comment: how would I check the credential? I normally use If ProfileDataset.Tables("RO_User").Rows.Count = 1 And strPassword.ToString <> ProfileDataset.Tables("RO_User").Rows(0).Item("User_psw").ToString Then... but now there's no place for me to place the hashbytes function

Comment: @user133466: Hash the credential in the same way as the original password.  If the hashes match, the strings are equal.

Comment: @user133466 - It should be noted you must do this in the db. I.e., pass the plain text password to the db, use Hashbytes on it and then return whether the result matches the hash stored in the db. Also, it means you are passing the plain text password in the clear to the db unless you encrypt the connection to the db.

Answer (score 2):

You should instead consider storing hashes of passwords instead of using encryption. In case you are unaware of the differences, a hash (also called a one way hash) takes an input and produces gobbledygook (called a hash) such that for the same input the same gobbledygook is produced. Authentication works by hashing what the user entered on the client and comparing it to the gobbledygook in the db. If they match, the passwords are the same. Without getting into specifics, hashes can never be reverted back to plain text which is their protection. Encryption however involves creating a cypher such that if you have the decryption key you can revert the cypher back to plain text.

If you are using SQL Server and ASP.NET, you should look into Forms Authentication with the SqlMembershipProvider.

[Explained: Forms Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx)

[SqlMembershipProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx)

[An Overview of Forms Authentication](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb)

Comment: This is exactly why we use salt that never leaves the database. The UI hash + salt = the database hash.

Comment: Upvote for MembershipProvider. To my mind you would need a really compelling reason not to use it. Also for gobbledygook.

Comment: @Simon: MembershipProvider ties you to an ASP.NET client.  It's also pretty hard to add new functionality to it.

Comment: @Andomar - The OP already said he was using ASP.NET (and SQL Server). First rule of security is not to do it yourself. If the user uses the Hashbytes function, they need to know about salts and the implications of passing the plain text all the way to the database

Comment: @Andomar: True, but given that the OP has stated that he is using ASP.NET and is asking about basics such as hashing I suspect that MembershipProvider will do all he needs for now. @user133466: I suggest you check it out and make an informed decision as to whether it meets your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have made this super-easy with the snappily named

`FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile`.

http://www.adventuresindevelopment.com/2009/05/23/a-simple-way-to-hash-passwords-in-aspnet/